# Remove first row before Export to CSV with gas script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to remove the first row before the CSV is generated.

I am not setting the range anywhere, so I  am not clear on how to proceed with removing the first row.

How to do this? Remove the first row of data.

I have:

gas function

```
function autoDownload() {
  let html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('download');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'CSV download dialog');
  Utilities.sleep(9000);
  
  let subFolderId = idP = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CSV Creation Temp Folder").next().getId();
  emptyFolder(subFolderId); // SubFolder Id
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function saveAsCSV() {
  let ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      ssname    = "sumApp-Headers",
      sheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(),
      ActiveGSN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  
  var ParentFolderIdx = createParentAndSubfolder("Header-Maker CSV Download", "CSV Creation Temp Folder");

  let folder = ParentFolderIdx;  Folder Id
  let params = ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv";
  let url    = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params;  
  let token  = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId(), {
        headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
        }
  });

  url = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder)
                .createFile(ssname, response, MimeType.CSV)
                .getDownloadUrl();
                     
  return url;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Auto Download CSV ... please wait
</body>
<script>
  function executeDownload(url) {
      window.location.href = url;
  }
  window.onload=function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(executeDownload)
      .saveAsCSV();
    window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9000);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How about copying the sheet, delete the first row, create csv of the copy?

Comment: I got it `let params = ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=csv&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + "&range=" + range;`  and `range is A1Notation` From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590082/delete-or-remove-first-row-of-google-sheet-script-export-to-csv

Comment: See [How to export Multiple sheets in (.csv) format in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74654152/13045193) for an alternative way. Use [Array.slice(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove the first row.